# MS Graph call fails with 504 for Onenote page content in Europe region. Response with status: 504 Gateway Timeout for URL

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api

We are getting response timeout for this call in Europe region, the same call works fine with South India data center.

```
Response with status: 504 Gateway Timeout for URL: 
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<userid>/onenote/pages/<pageId>/content
```

Is some upgrade is going on? Our customers are suffering from this.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I see that a few of such requests failed with 504 status code on 6/12 at about 9:12 AM UTC for application id 1064f7e4-a9e2-467d-8d42-f45cc59f145d - can you confirm that this is your appId?